# wifi stopped working RTL8821CE ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless

my wifi card stopped working after reboot.

The package rtl8821ce-dkms is installed, why is wifi gone?

```
$ dpkg -l  | grep rtl88
ii  rtl8821ce-dkms                                5.5.2.1-0ubuntu4~20.04.2              all          DKMS source for the Realtek 8821C PCIe WiFi driver
$ sudo modprobe -a rtl8821ae 
$ sudo rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNGEFORDERT     
       Beschreibung: Network controller
       Produkt: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:02:00.0
       Version: 00
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       Konfiguration: latency=0

dkms status
rtl8821ce, 5.5.2.1: added
virtualbox, 6.1.10, 5.4.0-59-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.10, 5.4.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed

uname -r 
5.8.0-36-generic
```

Comment: `dkms status` and `uname -r` please.

Comment: added the output

Comment: Obviously that driver that you installed is incompatible with the 5.8 kernel. You can boot with the `5.4.0-60-generic` and Wi-Fi will work. Your VirtualBox isn't working BTW ;-)

Comment: Hold on. I'll write an answer on how to fix it.

Comment: wifi is not working if I boot kernel 5.4.0-60, why is virtualbox not working with 5.8? All packages and driver are from the ubuntu repository.

Comment: Did it work before? It looks like it wasn't build for 5.4 as well because of the error with 5.8. Maintainers updated kernel but forgot about everything else.

Comment: I see that this version has been updated. But the module is not built. Connect to the internet and re-install `rtl8821ce-dkms`. Post output if any errors.

Comment: Run `sudo apt remove rtl8821ce-dkms && sudo apt install rtl8812ce-dkms`

Comment: it was working before, with rtl8821ce-dkms.  You really mean rtl8812ce-dkms?  rtl8821ce should be correct from lshw output. I reinstalled  rtl8821ce-dkms (remove + install) and it did not fix it.

Comment: Were there any errors? Did `dkms status` change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found a solution.

The problem was missing kernel header for 5.8. The package `linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04` was installed, but `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` was missing. Did not notice because no kernel 5.8 was installed before ...

After that `sudo apt remove rtl8821ce-dkms && sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms` restored wifi. (Thanks for your help! Pilot6)

```
dkms status
rtl8821ce, 5.5.2.1, 5.4.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821ce, 5.5.2.1, 5.8.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.10: added
```

Virtualbox kernel modules are still broken, but I think this is a general problem. Tried a complete purge and reinstall without success. :/
https://www.reddit.com/r/voidlinux/comments/ihnh51/linux58_building_dkms_module_virtualboxose6110/

Comment: There are all sorts of trouble with this upgrade. This is the correct solution. But you see that VB is not installed ;-) See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306463/i-am-unable-to-open-virtualbox

Comment: This chip RTL8821CE is poorly managed from reading github tomaspinho rtl8821ce.  Using Pilot6 suggestion remove && install fixed it for me on 5.13.0.30.  On occasional kernel upgrades and point releases I have to re-install this driver using tethering.  This time I found this and it worked quickly.

Comment: 5.13.0.39 kernel update knocked it out again and this fix did not work for me this time.  Ugh, trying the tomaspinho driver again. Disable secure boot https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce Download, unzip and rename folder from rtl8821ce-master to rtl8821ce then inside folder; sudo apt install bc module-assistant build-essential dkms then; sudo m-a prepare then; sudo ./dkms-install.sh  I did this before from a AU thread here but can't remember where I found it else I would link it instead.  I'll update later whether its valid for me and link if found.

Comment: Nothing worked for me until I uninstalled the driver without reinstalling it. [See here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401475/why-rtl8821ce-or-wifi-is-removed-during-kernel-update-on-20-04-4-lts/1401498#1401498)