# Just installed Ubuntu 23.04 but my wifi router is not being found

Tags: wireless

When first installing the Ubuntu operating system when prompted to set up a wifi network I entered the info for my phone's mobile hot-spot (Thank God) and I have been using that. First I was only connected to wifi when i was within the non GUI terminal environment but when I donwloaded firefox all of a sudden I am able to connect to wifi on the desktop environment now but I am unable to switch to my home network now (since I dont want to use all my data obviously) and it still says no wifi adapter found please help! Below are some entries related to my question:

```
jorjortaylor@jtf-server:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
Release:    23.04
Codename:   lunar
jorjortaylor@jtf-server:~$  -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
-nnk: command not found
jorjortaylor@jtf-server:~$  lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8821ce
jorjortaylor@jtf-server:~$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wifi stopped working RTL8821CE ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306507/wifi-stopped-working-rtl8821ce-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [network manager says "device not managed"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

**Shell Script:**

Created `wifi_setup.sh` script using nano text editor. Added:

```
sudo nmcli device set wlo1 managed yes
```

**Executable Script:**

Made the script executable:

```
chmod +x wifi_setup.sh.
```

**Startup Configuration:**

Set the script to run during system startup. Path: `/home/jorjortaylor/wifi_setup.sh`.

Note: I avoided restarting NetworkManager at any point as it caused my WiFi interface to revert to an unmanaged state.

This approach might not be conventional, but it worked when other solutions failed. Sharing this in the hope it helps others facing similar challenges.