# Error with Oracle Virtualbox installation on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox

I get the following error when starting Virtualbox

```
$ virtualbox 
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

Loading new virtualbox-6.1.10 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-36-generic
Building initial module for 5.8.0-36-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/virtualbox-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox:
 virtualbox depends on virtualbox-dkms (>= 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-source (>= 6.1.10
-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-modules; however:
  Package virtualbox-dkms is not configured yet.
  Package virtualbox-source is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-modules is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-dkms which provides virtualbox-modules is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt:
 virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1); however:
  Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
  Package virtualbox-6.1 which provides virtualbox is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failur
e.
  No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous fail
ure.
    Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-dkms
 virtualbox
 virtualbox-qt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I referred to several threads including the following one, but those common fixes mentioned does not work on my end.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60350358/how-do-i-resolve-the-character-device-dev-vboxdrv-does-not-exist-error-in-ubu

Comment: It's a bug with kernel 5.8 and Virtualbox 6.1.10.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305873/error-installing-virtualbox-dkms-on-ubuntu-20 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306463/i-am-unable-to-open-virtualbox

Comment: Install VB 6.1.16 from VB website.