# Errors were encountered while processing: virtualbox-dkms

Tags: apt, virtualbox

can you help me with this error:
Errors were encountered while processing:
virtualbox-dkms

I installed Oracle Virtualbox and it's working well.

```
$ sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for louisro: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'zoom' instead of './zoom_amd64.deb'
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kbuild libgsoap-2.8.91 libvncserver1 module-assistant virtualbox-source
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  zoom
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/45,9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 85,7 MB disk space will be freed.
Get:1 /home/louisro/zoom_amd64.deb zoom amd64 5.4.57862.0110 [45,9 MB]
(Reading database ... 266695 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack /home/louisro/zoom_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking zoom (5.4.57862.0110) over (3.5.392530.0421) ...
run post uninstall script, action is upgrade ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) ...
Removing old virtualbox-6.1.10 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.1.10
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-6.1.10 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-36-generic
Building initial module for 5.8.0-36-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/virtualbox-dkms
.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 10
Setting up zoom (5.4.57862.0110) ...
run post install script, action is configure...
Error in file "/usr/share/applications/org.kde.kdeconnect_open.desktop": "*/*" i
s an invalid MIME type ("*" is an unregistered media type)
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am unable to open virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306463/i-am-unable-to-open-virtualbox)  Also see:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305873/error-installing-virtualbox-dkms-on-ubuntu-20

Comment: Actually, no, because virtualbox launches properly, it's when I run apt install thatI get this error

Comment: Correct.  It is a bug with the 5.8 kernel and Virtualbox 6.1.10 and it will not be able to reinstall any part of it.  If you go back to the 5.4 kernel it will probably work fine.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, which kernel ? I don't want to downgrade anything, Oracle Virtualbox 6.1.16 is running pretty good. I got this error when installing something else as you can see on my first command `$ sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb`. What I want is to get rid of this error.

Comment: "Loading new virtualbox-6.1.10 DKMS files..." shows Virtualbox 6.1.10.  You don't have to downgrade, but reboot and go into Advanced in GRUB and choose the older kernel that starts with 5.4.  Or you can remove and reinstall Virtualbox from Virtualbox themselves to version 6.1.16 to fix the error you are getting.  Your error isn't dealing with Zoom install, but a messed up Virtualbox.

Comment: I am worried about loading the older kernel, will all the rest of the system be stable? 
I'd like better to remove and reinstall, can you point me to the right commands ? Thank you

Comment: If the system was working fine with the 5.4 kernel it would still be stable and fine.  That is the reason why the last kernel does not get auto removed when a new kernel gets installed so that you have a fall back to go to.  As far as the Virtualbox goes, you can follow https://askubuntu.com/a/1305883/231142 to install it from the Repo provided by Virtualbox themselves.  Other companies like Calibre also recommend using their direct version vs using the one from the distro as the distro version can be frozen and not update.

Comment: ok thanks, I did the procedure you linked and it's to work. Thanks a lot